# Format date from database to table using php

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I have a database full of football fixtures, sorted in descending order. Everything works fine however the dates are in the following format: YYYYMMDD like so - 2014-05-11.

All table contents are selected with:

```
 $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Fixtures ORDER BY Date DESC");
```

Then inserted into the table with the below code:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {

  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Date'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Home Team'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Score'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Away Team'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Score1'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Competition'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
```

How can I make it so these dates appear DDMMYYYY such as 11-05-2014?

Thanks!

Comment: Manual for `date` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Manual for equivalent in MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution:

```
echo "<td>" . date('d-m-Y', strtotime($row['Date'])) . "</td>";
```

[Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: that'd only work if mysql actually returns a unix timestamp. `date('d-m-Y', '2014-04-28')` isn't going to work at all.

Comment: Hi, Just tried this method and all dates are now set as: 31-12-1969??

Answer (score 1):

Use **[DateTime::createFromFormat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)**

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('dmY', $row['Date']);
echo $date->format('d-m-Y');
```

Comment: without sounding like an idiot how would I put this into my code?

Comment: DateTime::createFromFormat will accept the date from a specified form. Like in your case its dmY, then `$date->format('d-m-Y')` will hold the format as you want. DateTime is a powerful class in PHP to handle datetime conversion and should be used intead of other conversion technique which are not always correct. You can add the first line inside the loop and then `echo "<td>" . $date . "</td>";`  thats all.

Answer (score 1):

Either fetch it properly from the database:

```
$query = "SELECT
    ...,
    ...,
    DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%d-%m-%Y') AS Date
FROM Fixtures
ORDER BY Date DESC";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

Or format it in your PHP

```
echo date('d-m-Y', $row['Date']);
```

Comment: Am i doing something wrong with my method? I don't have much knowledge in PHP so thought this would be fine. Without sounding too much like a noob, how would i implement your above code into mine?